# Jawbone UP4.. getting the GSR values

Tags: api, jawbone

How do i get the GSR (Galvanic Skin Response) and Respiration data? It appears that the information is just used by the band to calculate the other values returned by the API.. Can i get this data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: @zhon what's wrong with this question?

Comment: In general, asking yes-or-no questions is a good thing to avoid unless you want a yes-or-no answer.

Comment: The first question starts with "How." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Jawbone does not make this data available through the [public API](http://developer.jawbone.com).

However, if you're trying to access this data for some kind of research project, you can send details to research@jawbone.com